# XCode 14 SwiftUI dyld symbol not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, audiokit, xcode14

I get this error when I run my code on an iOS 14 device using XCode 14.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI15GraphicsContextV4fill_4with5styleyAA4PathV_AC7ShadingVAA9FillStyleVtF
Referenced from: ******
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI

 dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
 DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
 DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

I do not get any errors when I run the same code on an iOS 15 or iOS 16 device.

How do I resolve this issue?

EDIT: Removing AudioKit and AudioKitUI swift packages resolves the issue. AudioKit developers need to look into this.